# Can't load SLF4J config from logback.xml file

Tags: tomcat, logging, slf4j

I am trying to set default logging level to be "OFF". In order to do that I have created loggback.xml file where I store my configuration. The content of the config file is as following.

```
<configuration>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
   <encoder>
     <pattern>
        %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
      </pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>


  <root level="OFF">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```

I placed file into WEB-INF/lib folder however it seems that this configuration is never loaded. Not sure what else it needs.

As a side note I have setup eclipse to run my webapp, so all Tomcat messages appear in the eclipse console.

Comment: Revise the application's log to see which logback.xml config file is being used, may be there is another one that is loaded first.

Answer (score 1):

Don't place the file in WEB-INF/lib but rather on your resources folder and let Maven/Ant do their job to put it at top level in classpath. Have a look [at this tutorial](https://wiki.base22.com/display/btg/How+to+setup+SLF4J+and+LOGBack+in+a+web+app+-+fast).